# url does not match in form action (python django)

Tags: python, django

***views***

```
def Editprograme1(request,addprogrammodel_id):
    try:
        username1 = request.session.get("ChooseUserName")

    except AddProgramModel.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404('<h1>page not exist</h1>')
    return render(request, 'addprograme1.html', {'member_data': member_data})
```

**URL:**

```
url(r'^Editprograme1/(?P<addprogrammodel_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.Editprograme1, name='Editprograme1'),
```

**html form:**

```
form method="post" action="{% url 'nwe1:Editprograme1' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

**Error:**

NoReverseMatch at /Editprograme1/1/
Reverse for 'Editprograme1' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['Editprograme1/(?P[0-9]+)/$']

Comment: You need to pass a value for the `addprogrammodel_id` parameter, so `{% url 'nwe1:Editprograme1' value_for_addprogrammodel_id %}`.

Comment: NoReverseMatch at /Editprograme1/1/
Reverse for 'Editprograme1' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['Editprograme1/(?P<addprogrammodel_id>[0-9]+)/$']

Comment: its raised an error kind of.

Comment: of yourse you need to replace `value_for_addprogrammodel_id` with a real value (an integer one).

Comment: error not fixed

Comment: this one fixed it:                                         path(r'^Editprograme1/addprogrammodel_id/$', views.Editprograme1, name='Editprograme1'),